# Error in Factorial Program in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, factorial

When I execute the below code in Python 3, it's gives me below error. 
Could some one explain me what is wrong in the below code.

I know how to write a Factorial Program using simple function. But I would like to understand what is wrong in the below code.

```
class Factorial:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n=1
    def fact(self,n):    
        if self.n >= 1:
            return ((self.n) * (self.fact(n - 1)))
        else:
            return 1
a=Factorial()
print("4! =", a.fact(4))
```

Error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: You never alter `self.n`.

Comment: Beyond not changing `self.n`, I think you don't need a `Class` for that. You are getting confused on what is `n` (arg) and `self.n` (param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never alter `self.n`, so it'll **always** be greater or equal to 1. You created an endless loop. It's set to `1` in `__init__` so `self.n >= 1` is true each time you test.

You should not use a local variable *and* a parameter to track the current state of the factorial function. Pick one or the other.

Without a parameter:

```
class Factorial:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def fact(self):
        n = self.n
        if n >= 1:
            self.n -= 1
            return n * self.fact()
        else:
            return 1
```

Note that you now pass the initial value of `n` to the *class*, to create an instance:

```
>>> f = Factorial(4)
>>> f.fact()
24
>>> f.n
0
```

This isn't all that useful, because now the instance has `n` set to `0`. Unless you assign something different to that attribute, calling `f.fact()` again will only produce `1` now.

This is not really a problem that needs to be solved with a class. If you pass the initial value of `n` is as a pramater, you don't need an instance to track the state and you can just use a normal function:

```
def fact(n):
    if n >= 1:
        return n * fact(n - 1)
    else:
        return 1
```

The `fact()` function can be called as often as needed, with different values for `n`:

```
>>> fact(4)
24
>>> fact(8)
40320
```

Comment: @MFisherKDX: indeed, because `self.n` is never set to anything but 1.

Answer (score -2):

You can change the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit`.

Comment: That is not the problem here.. this is an infinite loop (won't mater recursion limit)

Comment: You can't fix an endless loop by altering the recursion limit. And the recursion limit is there for a reason; you'll just get a segfault instead when your stack exceeds the permitted limitations.